# Where is libfreetype.so.6 in OpenJDK, I got an unsatisfiedLinkError when using a kaptcha jar

Tags: java

I run my program in suse 11 operation system. The JRE is OpenJDK 8u-191. The program runs smoothly except kaptcha for login. When I login the page will show me the kaptcha, but an exception occurs.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/java8/jre-8u191/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so: libfreetype.so.6: cannot open shared object file no such file or directory

at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)

...

Is the libfreetype.so.6 in OpenJDK? I can't find it. Should I download the libfreetype.so.6 from internet?

Comment: What operating system / distribution / version are you using?   If you are using Linux, you should install the appropriate package from the package manager (apt, yum, dnf, whatever).  The package name will depend on your Linux distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of libfreetype6 and you can find it here https://software.opensuse.org/package/libfreetype6

Comment: fontconfig may also be required (it was for me):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73543024/how-to-install-font-on-linux