# How to install font on linux

Tags: java, linux, fonts, java-17, fontconfig

I am using windows os, So there is no issue with Font(java.awt) class object creation. but my testing environment is on linux. So on that I am getting NULL POINTER exception.

```
Cannot load from short array because "sun.awt.FontConfiguration.head" is null
```

After seacrhing I found that there should be fonts folder in usr/share directory on linux.
So someone can please suggest. Do I have to just copy fonts to that directory or there is other way to intsall?

Comment: I think that could vary between distros but do you actually need to install it? You could use ```java.awt.Font createFont```  with the font file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For my configuration (java.18/Spring Boot/jib/Docker/ubuntu) I've used this these commands for resolving the issue:

```
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils    --no-install-recommends
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6 --no-install-recommends
RUN apt-get install -y fontconfig   --no-install-recommends
RUN apt-get install -y fonts-dejavu --no-install-recommends
```

Comment: another try could be 


RUN yum -y install freetype
RUN yum -y install fontconfig
RUN yum -y install harfbuzz
RUN yum -y install glibc