# Unable to use SXSSFWorkbook - Apache POI inside docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I'm working on Spring Boot. I'm try to write a huge excel file, so I need to use SXSSFWorkbook from Apache POI. I run the service via **'mvn spring-boot:run'** and everything is working normally. But when I run the service via docker. I got this error,

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/java/openjdk/lib/libfontmanager.so: libfreetype.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here is my Dockerfile,

```
# For Java 11, try this
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre

# Refer to Maven build -> finalName
ARG JAR_FILE=target/customer-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

# cd /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

# java -jar /opt/app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -jar", "-jar","app.jar"]
```

How should I fix this. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720878/where-is-libfreetype-so-6-in-openjdk-i-got-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-using-a

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to missing font in your OS/ container image, in your case either try a different Java image or install the necessary Font to the Docker container host.

Just instead of "adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre" try this "openjdk:11".

Answer (score 0):

After ApachePOI 5.2.4, you can set system property, what I have found on apache forum:

```
@Configuration
public class FontConfiguration {

@PostConstruct
public void setProperty() {
    System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.ss.ignoreMissingFontSystem", "true");
}
}
```

If you don't use extra features in your XLSX workbook, this helps you avoid the UnsatisfiedLinkError.